# How to report Click-Jacking abuse with Facebook Social Plugins

Tags: facebook, clickjacking

How to report a website that use Click-Jacking with social plugins to increase likes?

I did not find the page that I report this action, the page "Reports" (https://www.facebook.com/help/263149623790594/) option did not appear related to the plugin.

Comment: Look through [Report a Violation](https://www.facebook.com/help/263149623790594/) in their help section …

Comment: Cbre, i didn't found there, only have app related.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/274459462613911